# How to save synthesized audio during streaming distribution

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I would like to stream a composite of microphone audio and digital sound sources by ffmpeg and save the delivery to an m3u8 file.

Below are the commands I have actually tried.

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 100M -f dshow -i video=<my webcam>:audio=<my microphone> -re -stream_loop -1 -i <my sound source> -filter_complex "[0]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,adelay=2100|2100,volume@voice=volume=10dB[voice],[1]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,azmq,volume@bgm=volume=0.2[bgm],[voice][bgm]amerge=inputs=2[out]" -map 0:v -map [out]:a -f mpegts -flush_packets 0 udp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXX?pkt_size=1316 -f hls -hls_time 5 hls.m3u8
```

I have played an m3u8 created this way, but I cannot hear the digital sound source that I am supposed to have synthesized.
Even though the synthesized audio was audible when streamed.

Perhaps you need to set up something like `-map 0:v -map [out]:a` when saving to the m3u8 file, in which case the `Output with label 'out' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.` message appears and does not work.

Comment: I think you need to use `amix` instead of `amerge`. `amerge` adds channels (e.g., 2 stereo inputs yield 4 channel audio). You streaming container may be supporting only stereo and dropping the 2 others channels that you merged.

Comment: @kesh Thanks for your quick response.
I have replaced `amerge` with `amix` and removed the stereo setting by container.

`ffmpeg -rtbufsize 100M -f dshow -i video=<my cam>:audio=<my mic> -re -stream_loop -1 -i <my sound> -filter_complex "[0]volume@voice=volume=20dB[voice],[1]azmq,volume@bgm=volume=0.2[bgm],[voice][bgm]amix=inputs=2[out]" -map 0:v -map [out]:a -f mpegts -flush_packets 0 udp://192.168.117.39:1234?pkt_size=1316 -f hls -hls_time 5 hls.m3u8`

However, the situation remains the same.Do I have to explicitly specify a type other than stereo?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. In general, I keep my filtergraphs as simple as possible and only add more as needed (just my preference, not necessarily the "right" way). The `amix` was what I noticed last night right before went to bed but I see your fundamental problem is lacking the mapping on your second output (as you mentioned). See my answer and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The `-map` options are defined per output, so if you have 2 outputs with the same mapping, you need to map separately (as you guessed it). The error message is saying the `[out]` stream has already been taken by the first output. See if adding `asplit` to the end and produce output stream for each stream fix the issue:

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 100M -f dshow -i video=<my cam>:audio=<my mic> \
       -stream_loop -1 -i <my sound> \
       -filter_complex "[0]volume@voice=volume=20dB[voice],[1]azmq,volume@bgm=volume=0.2[bgm]; \
                        [voice][bgm]amix=inputs=2,asplit[out1][out2]" \
       -map 0:v -map [out1] -f mpegts -flush_packets 0 udp://192.168.117.39:1234?pkt_size=1316 \
       -map 0:v -map [out2] -f hls -hls_time 5 hls.m3u8
```

I've seen inconsistent behaviors on the handling of the filter output labels, so a bit surprised by the error you're getting. (are you using the latest master/releaee?)

A couple other things:

1. `-re` shouldn't be needed on the second input url. That option is reserved to simulated real-time streaming and not to be used for streaming.
2. `-amix` `weights` option as an alternative to your current implementation with `azmq` and `volume`. They do a slightly different things so you may have already considered it, but I thought I'd mention it here just in case as it shortens your filtergraph by a good bit. Something like this:

```
-filter_complex "[1]azmq,[0]amix=inputs=2:weights=1|0.2,asplit[out1][out2]"
```